# Adding all string constants from a class to a List of string constants in C#

Tags: c#, constants

I have a class,

```
        public static class Permissions
        {
            public const string AccessRightFormAdmin = "TEST1";
            public const string AccessRightExperimental = "TEST2";
        }
```

I want to have `List<string> myConsts = new List<string>;` such that, `myConsts` contains all the string constants from the `Permissions` class. How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: You're probably going to have to do it manually, or use reflection to accomplish this. Have you considered using an enum instead? It would achieve your goal in a simpler manner.

Comment: smells like XY problem - why do you need to do this?

Comment: start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-6.0

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you put it in a list it's not const anymore. And you would have to access them by index which is bad for readability.

Comment: Keep them in a list to start with, and make those fields into read only properties that pull from the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to manually maintain your `myConsts` collection, you will have to use reflection.

```
public readonly List<string> myConsts = 
    typeof(Permissions)
        .GetFields()
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(null).ToString())
        .ToList();
```

This looks at the `Permissions` type, selects all public fields, then pulls the values from those FieldInfo into a new collection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of string, better to use KeyValuePair, this way constants can be used  the same way as enumerations.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> consts = typeof(Permission).GetFields()
.Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string,string> ( p.Name, (string)p.GetValue(null))).ToList();
```

result

```
AccessRightFormAdmin    TEST1
AccessRightExperimental TEST2
```

Comment: But, if I add things to Permission class then I have to update my List as well, trying to avoid that.

Comment: Why do you need to keep 2 copies? It doesn't make any sense.